# react-pdf on server side

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I am trying to use react-pdf to create pdf document on the server side. However on running my express server I get this error

```
 <Document>
   ^

 SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Please help me solve this !

Also I am trying to use react-pdf library on node express server.
I have installed react and react-pdf/renderer

Answer (score 2):

react-pdf is used to display existing PDFs. If you wish to create PDFs using React, you may be looking for @react-pdf/renderer.

A Great library to create pdfs and fill forms is pdf-lib. I am using react-pdf to render my pdf, and pdf-lib to make any changes to pdfs.